# Set Variable in Ghost inspector for clicking on cards/tiles on website

Tags: ui-automation

I am using ghost inspector to record for ecommerce site where products are in tile view (or say grid view). I have recorded this for one product but now I want to do same cycle of selecting other products on listing page. How can I do this? I just have an idea I can use spreadsheet but how can I pass parameters there?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoFLM.png)

so basically I want to click on the products in the grid.

Answer (score 1):

So you can use a spreadsheet in ghost inspector but that's for [data driven testing](https://ghostinspector.com/docs/data-driven-testing/). For example, if you have a login screen and you want to test a combination of various different usernames or passwords you could create `{{username}}` and `{{password}}` [as variables in your test steps](https://ghostinspector.com/docs/variables/) and then put multiple login/password combinations in a spreadsheet to use for those variable.

However, it seems what you're doing is actually an "action" not entering data. Therefore, if you want to click every single product on the grid you have a couple options,

1) Create multiple tests. one for each tile/product. (probably the most inefficient as it will run up your ghost inspector test runs. so only do this if you absolutely see no other way)

2) Create one test where you click on each tile, go back click on another tile, ect. (i don't know how many tiles/products you have, so I don't know how feasibe this is either.)

3) Execute Javascript and write a loop? potentially, but that really depends on your website and you javascript knowledge.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for help Aaron however I could find a better way. To solve it with spreadsheet and passing hrefs(what needs to be appended to domain) to one column. The only issue with this is if someone else wants to run the script  they will have to have the file from me since it is desktop copy and there is no way I can keep in ghost inspector for "click" action.